# Command like "paste - -", but sorted alphabetical

Tags: text-processing, sort

I have a textfile like:

```
Adam
Bob
Cevin
David
Evan
```

If I "paste - -" it, I get:

```
Adam   Bob
Cevin  David
Evan
```

But I need that the lower half will be added as a new column:

```
Adam  David
Bob   Evan
Cevin
```

Is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: So you want to split the input file in two columns while retaining its order?

Comment: Yeah right, pr -t2 worked :)

Comment: Looks like you want to print the columns _down_ rather than _across_, and it doesn't have much to do with sorting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use:

```
pr -t -2 file
```

Beware it truncates the lines that are wider than half the page width (72 characters by default, see the `-w` option to change it).

(note that [with the GNU implementation, the column alignment may be off if the file contains multi-byte or zero-width or double-width characters](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24924)). Or:

```
pr -t -2 -s file
```

to separate the columns with one tab character like `paste` does (there's no truncation then).

Note however that `pr` treats the form-feed character (`^L`) as a page delimiter. Not a problem if that character is not present in your file.

Or with `zsh`:

```
print -r -C2 -- ${(f)"$(<file)"}
```

- `$(<file)`: grab the content of `file`
- `(f)`: split it on line**f**eed (newline) characters
- `-r`: print **r**aw
- `-C2`: on **2** **C**olumns.

Comment: I've tried reading the man page for `pr` and couldn't find where it accepts a number after `-t`... would you tell me? I always find man pages  difficult. thanks!

Comment: @JorgeeFG That's not a number after `-t`, that's the `-2` option. `-COLUMN, --columns=COLUMN` in the GNU `pr` man page. I'll break the `-t2` down in the answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: So do you mean for the other types of characters, you suggest we use `pr`, but a non-GNU implementation?

Comment: @Pysis, if you care about column alignment with non-ASCII text, then yes. You could try the `pr` from the heirloom toolchest which seems to work OK.